# Apns key vs Certificate

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to enable Push Notifications for a new App ID but I'm required to create an SSL cert (dev or prod) for the App ID, even if I’ve already created an Apns Key and configured it in my push notificaton gateway.

Why is this required in my app id push capability ?